# "SQL Default Mailer - Job failed" will not stop sending me mail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I had a stored procedure due to run every day at 3am which failed last night (had edited SP and forgot to add a comma in the right place).

This morning I had ~15k emails in my inbox telling me that my job had failed. Fair enough I deleted them all, fixed the error in SQL Server Management Studio, check it works now and applied it.

Emails are still coming through, 60 at a time.

Ok, I change the job to stop emailing while I figure stuff out.

Emails are still coming through.

I try to stop the job but am told that I can't stop it when it's not running.

Emails are still coming through.

Delete the entire job.

"Ditto".

Any ideas?

Update: Nothing running on SQL Server Agent. Stopped SQL Server Agent and started it again. Back up to a couple of thousand emails.